# adding two Co-major professor to my thesis

Tags: thesis

I am working on my thesis and using a custom document class.
I am trying to add two co-major professors.

This is just part of what I have on the cls file regarding defining the major professor:

```
\def\majorprofessor#1{\def\@majorprofessor{#1}}
\def\@majorprofessor{\missingalert{No \noexpand\majorprofessor given}}
\def\majorproftitle#1{\def\@majorproftitle{#1}}
\def\@majorproftitle{\missingalert{No \noexpand\majorproftitle given}}
```

How can I modify it to have two co-major professors?

The command on the my document is

```
\majorprofessor{John, Ph.D.}
```

What is the command for two Co-major professors?

The link below is the Dissertation template uploaded by my university.
https://usf.app.box.com/s/h5lhgajsoi65f8zunjpak52i32q3lyou

Thanks

Comment: This question is almost completely meaningless out of context. How are these commands used in your document and what do they affect? What document class are you using and are these commands part of it or part of some package? Post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) if you can and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, all the code you posted does is define a command that can be used to define another command (and also sets a default to the other command in case the first command is never used). You could make as many of those as you wanted `\def\majorprofessortwo#1{\def\@majorprofessortwo{#1}}`, but that's not going to have any effect on your document unless you actually put it to use somewhere.

Comment: Sorry the edit doesn't help much. It's pretty clear how the commands `\majorprofessor` and `\majorproftitle` are used. The question is how are the commands *defined by them* (`\@majorprofessor` and `\@majorproftitle`) used? Where are these actually used? What do they do? In other words, what in the document changes if you change `\majorprofessor{John, Ph.D.}` to `\majorprofessor{Jane, Ph.D.}`? Trust me, no one can help you without that information. Again, post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Editing classes is incredible tricky. It demands knowing not only LaTeX, and normally also TeX but also the standards to be follow and how things interact with each other. Editing a class we don't even have access to is a work that also demands a crystal ball. The laziest possible solution is to create a `@minorprofessor` macro and insert the result somewhere near where the `@majorprofessor` is located.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I add a link that includes all the files for the dissertation template uploaded by my university @frabjous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two co-major professors you should use `\and` command inside `\majorprofessor` in the following way:

```
\majorprofessor{John, Ph.D. \and Smith, Ph.D.}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrey L.